# echo to file from nested script bash

Tags: bash

I am a newbie in bash. I have two scripts - script1 that goes over a directory and for each file in it performs script2 on the file.

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find ../myFiles/ -type f); do
   $( cat $file | ./script2) >> res.txt
done
```

script2:

```
while read line;
do   ...
  ....
  echo "$line"
done
```

however the `echo "$line"` in script2 does not work as i want it (to the res.txt file), but it is outputed as a command, resulting in an error ("command not found")

Does somesone know how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Try - `echo $line` without double quotes. Also in script1, does the line `$( cat ..` work? You need something like `\`cat $file | ./script2\` >> res.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`$( foo )` executes the results of the command `foo`, exactly as you described. Do:

```
./script2 < "$file" >> res.txt
```

There's no need to create a pipe and running stuff is what bash does. "`echo`" is an external command. So is "`[`" (as in: `if [ thing ]`), though in reality bash handles those internally. You can still run `[` as a standalone program though. Type: `which [` to see.

*Edit:* in case that wasn't clear enough:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find ../myFiles/ -type f); do
    ./script2 < "$file" >> res.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is easier if you approach it with functions:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

search_path='.'                                                                  

### declare functions ###                                                        
function foo {                                                                   
  for file in `find $search_path -type f`                                        
  do                                                                             
    echo 'processing: '$file                                                     
    process_file $file                                                           
  done                                                                           
}                                                                                

function process_file {                                                          
  while read line                                                                
  do                                                                             
    echo $line                                                                   
  done < $file                                                                   
}                                                                                

### call your main function ###                                                  
foo
```

It easier to read and also to modify in case you need extra functionality later.
One script is enough also.

(A cool thing is that, as it is, the script will print itself.)

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` is used for command substitution. Consider following scripts:

**script1:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file; do
   ./script2 "$file" >> res.txt
done < <(find . -name "file" -type f)
```

**script2:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  echo "$line"
done < "$1"
```